# High memory usage c# webbrowser for a touch screens

Tags: c#, winforms, input, memory-leaks

I am looking for a solution to the problem for over a week. Currently, I creating a browser for a touch screen. I created my own keyboard (Form2), which opens when the browser has the status of input (e.g search engine in google) . Everything works great but when i start to browse memory begins to exceed more than 300 mb after 5 minutes.

This is an incorrect code that causes problems with memory - without this everything it's ok.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement input in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))

        {

            if (input.GetAttribute("type").ToLower() == "text")
            {
                input.GotFocus += AttachKeyboard;
                input.LostFocus += RemoveKeyboard;

            }

        }

     }
public void AttachKeyboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2.Instance.Show();        
    }
public  void RemoveKeyboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2.Instance.Hide();
    }
```

I tried unsubscribe from the event with `-=`but with no effect.
Problem tested on Windows 7, 8, 10
Thank you very much for any help. I'm starting to learn C# language.

edit
When i delete this line, everything it's ok.

```
            input.GotFocus += AttachKeyboard;
            input.LostFocus += RemoveKeyboard;
```

Comment: How did you unsubscribe?  It might be better to create an event of your own and set the event to `null` whenever the browser navigates away.

Comment: Right Click on Project in Solution Explorer and Select Properties > Click on the Debug Tab > Uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" checkbox under the Enable Debuggers Section. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Jeremy Thompson I tried to uncheck but the idea didn't fix the problem. Luke Park I tried to unsubscribe or set event to null with                         if (input.GetAttribute("type").ToLower() == "text")
            {
                input.GotFocus += AttachKeyboard;
                input.LostFocus += RemoveKeyboard;

            }
            else                                                                                                            {input.GotFocus -= AttachKeyboard;
                input.LostFocus -= RemoveKeyboard; } No effects

Comment: Guys, How to properly delete/dispose this handlers?